# Directory Structure for saving image files in Java/Jersey REST project (Maven)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jersey-2.0

I'm new to Maven projects, so appreciate some advice on this. I have a jersey REST project with the following directory structure:

[image]

My plan is to use `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` to save the file to the disk and save the path to file to DB via hibernate.

As for storing the images, I'm planning to create a new folder under `src/main/resource` called `img` (that is at the same level as `hibernate.cfg.xml`) and save the images there.

Questions:

1. Is my approach correct? Any better suggestions?
2. Do I need to change the `pom.xml` to add any tag. My current `pom.xml` is as follows

   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

   ```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
   <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>xxx</name>

   <build>
       <finalName>xxx</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.1</version>
               <inherited>true</inherited>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
               <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
               <version>${jersey.version}</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
           <!-- jersey -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
           <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
           <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
       </dependency>
       <!-- JSON support -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <!-- postgresql -->
           <dependency>
           <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
           <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
           <version>42.1.4</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- hibernate -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>cglib</groupId>
           <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
           <version>3.2.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- logging for hibernate -->
       <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
               <version>1.7.25</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
               <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
               <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
               <version>1.2.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- password hashing -->
       <dependency>
               <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
               <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
               <version>0.3m</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- http client -->
       <dependency>
               <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
               <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
               <version>3.9.0</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <properties>
       <jersey.version>2.25</jersey.version>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Storing user data like images inside web application including `WEB-INF` directory is not a good and recommended approach.

You are planning to store images in `src/main/resource/img` directory, but this is just development project structure. For deploying it on actual server, you have to first make a `war` file and then deploy it. After deployment, this `src/main/resource/img` directory would come inside `WEB-INF` directory and user data will get stored there.

Now, think of the situation, when you have to deploy upgraded version of the web application or you want to move web application to different server. For only web application, it would be easy to just deploy `war` file but what will happen for this user images. Another problem is this is user data, so how you will keep backup of such data so that it wouldn't get lost in case of hardware failure.

Recommended approach for storing user images, if image file size is small, it is better to store in database as `binary` data. If image file size is big, then you should consider to store it in some external server or outside of your web application directory where frequent backup of the data can be configured and then store path of the image in database.